# How to get the frame size of a UIImageView in a UICollectionView cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to get the frame size of a `UIImageView` inside a `UICollectionViewCell`. I have currently tried to achieve this using `thumbnailImageView.frame.size` but this returns `(0.0, 0.0)` no matter where I call this method from.

The reason I want to do this is to round the edges of the image inside the image view, but as I am using `.scaleAspectFit` I need to know the frame size and image size to correctly round the corners.

Below is the cell class:

```
class SomeCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let thumbnailImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return imageView
    }()

    private func setLabel(label: UILabel, textSize: CGFloat = 15.0, textColour: UIColor = UIColor.black) -> UILabel {
        label.textColor = textColour
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = label.font.withSize(textSize)
        return label
    }

    var firstLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    var secondLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    var thirdLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

    func setupViews() {
        firstLabel = setLabel(label: firstLabel)
        secondLabel = setLabel(label: secondLabel)
        thirdLabel = setLabel(label: thirdLabel)

        addSubview(thumbnailImageView)
        addSubview(firstLabel)
        addSubview(secondLabel)
        addSubview(thirdLabel)

        addConstraintWithFormat(format: "V:|-25-[v0(125)]-[v1(16)]-[v2(16)]-[v3(17)]-25-|", views: thumbnailImageView, firstLabel, secondLabel, thirdLabel)
        addConstraintWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: thumbnailImageView)
        addConstraintWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: firstLabel)
        addConstraintWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: secondLabel)
        addConstraintWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: thirdLabel)

    }

}

extension UIView {
    func addConstraintWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...) -> Void {
        var viewDictionary = [String : UIView]()
        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            viewDictionary[key] = view
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary))
    }
}
```

Comment: let imageViewSize = cell.yourImageView.frame.size

Comment: @ElTomato I tried this and it still return (0.0, 0.0).

Comment: Then either your IBOutlet object is not connected or you are not telling the whole story.

Comment: I am not using the storyboard. The image is being displayed correctly within the collection view.

Comment: Try to get frame in layoutSubviews()

Comment: @AainaJain this returns `()`

Comment: Can you show the code where you configure the image view?

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan I have added the cell class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution to the problem was to use this method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }
```

This method is used to tell the delegate that the specified cell is about to be displayed in the collection view and at this point, it has been given it's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want, try it:

```
print(cell.photo?.image.size)
```

Comment: No, this gives the original image size before the aspectRatio has chages it. I need the ImageView size to calculated the size of the new image after the AspectRatiio has changed it.

Answer (score 0):

one more possibility print(cell.frame.size)